# how to set and get URL parameters on a search field

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs, search, filter

Can somebody correct me on how these codes will work-in? I know these are not a working code’s. I am having trouble on how to pass the URL parameters name and start date. I want to make a search button like if you type the name “peter” and then if you going to click it. It will show all names “peter” and then the **[URL](http://staging.api.sample.com/events.json?name=peter)**. same as the start date like if you type 2015-01-01 the **[url](http://staging.api.sample.com/events.json?start_Date_from=2015-01-01)**

Pls help me guys. I don’t have an idea about these.The code below is like.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myTable">
    <head>
        <title>project  43</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myTable = angular.module('myTable', []);
            myTable.controller('tableCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
                $http.get("", {headers: {Authorization: 'vuNYhXbpKfH7dxkL4h1o2etBJDEiVrRdsds'}})
                        .success(function (response) {
                            debugger
                            $scope.members = response.events;
                            $scope.totals = response.paging;
                        });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="tableCtrl">
        <table border="5">
            <tr>
                <th>Event</th>
                <th>Account Shop</th>
                <th>Place</th>
                <th>Activity</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="member in members">
                <td>
                    {{member.Event.name}}<br>  <!--names-->
                    {{member.Event.id}}<br>
                    {{member.Event.date_start}}<br>   <!--Start Date-->
                    {{member.Event.date_end}}<br> 
                <td>
                    {{member.AccountShop.id}}<br>
                    {{member.AccountShop.name}}<br>
                    {{member.AccountShop.short_code}}<br>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <div ng-repeat="Place in member.Place">
                        {{Place.id}}<br>
                        {{Place.name}}<br>
                        {{Place.lk_country_code}}<br>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div ng-repeat="Activity in member.Activity">
                        {{Activity.id}}<br>
                        {{Activity.short_description}}
                    </div>
                </td>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope, this code help you little bit.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>


<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="">
<div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', date:'03-AUG-2015'},
                     {name:'Mary', date:'01-AUG-2015'},
                     {name:'Mike', date:'25-JUL-2015'},
                     {name:'Adam', date:'03-AUG-2015'},
                     {name:'Julie', date:'07-JUN-2015'},
                     {name:'Juliette', date:'23-FEB-2015'}]"></div>

 <label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
 <div id="searchTextResults">
 <div ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
  <a href="http://staging.api.sample.com/events.json?name={{friend.name}}&&date={{friend.date}}">
{{friend.name}} | {{friend.date}} </a>  
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort @babu pasungily . But my boss want to make it like getting URL parameters like $location.search()name . But I dunno how it works ha-ha . i really appreciated ya effort . :) , hope you can suggest more about dis. tnx